# Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am having a crash with the following exception on Android device SM-J727U but not on other devices. I read through some stack overflow answers and it is effecting only some new android devices on Android 7.0.

Can any one suggest how to resolve it and what is causing it to happen.

Thanks
R

Here is the exception.

```
    Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException', reason: 'Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}' 
Last Exception Backtrace
0   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView
1   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView
2   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
3   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:476)
4   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1105)
5   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1018)
6   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
7   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
8   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:176)
9   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
10  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
11  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
```

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_user_full_names"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:theme="@style/EmployeeFieldLabel"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_english_characters_only">           

     <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_full_names"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/EmployeeFieldTextStyle"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/names_as_it_appears_on_id"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Styles

```
<style name="EmployeeFieldLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#9e9e9e</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dp_text_size_medium</item>

    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blueyPurple</item>
</style>

<style name="EmployeeFieldTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dp_text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_field</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

The cause for this is Google spell checker popup, enabled in some devices which causes red line under words in Edittext

Use this

**In your Styles**

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight"></item>
```

*In Your xml*

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Instead of

```
 android:inputType="textPersonName"


 <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blueyPurple</item>
```

Comment: Hello @sandeep with these changes effect UI on other devices?, can you give a brief explanation on how these changes will impact please

Comment: [Check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout) it will hep you to learn about this and text [inputtype](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType)

Comment: Hi Sandeep thank you for the info. I have changed the input type to  textNoSuggestions as you suggested. do you think colorControlActivated can be the cause fir the crash as well?

Comment: @SandeepParish can you provide some more detail? How does this solve the problem. What about 'spell checker popup' causes this crash on some devices?